# How to pass data into a modal in AngularJS on click event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, dom, angular-ui

Here's my problem:

I'm converting a simple data tracking application into an SPA using AngularJS. I have table with clickable dates in my HTML template that displays some data. Each button is assigned an id which is derived from the ObjectId property in my database. My goal is the hook these buttons up for update functionality, and I need to autopopulate the form. I can query the API I built previously and get data back, but I have been unable to expose it to my modal.

My API is already constructed and tested. The modal works, it opens and closes when I want and the form looks good.

My table markup:

```
<tbody ng-repeat="flt in vm.data.flights">
  <tr>
    <td><a ng-attr-id="{{ flt._id }}" ng-click="vm.popupReviewForm()" class="btn btn-default">{{flt.fltDate}}</a></td>
    <td>{{flt.hobbsIn}}</td>
    <td>{{flt.hobbsOut}}</td>
    <td>{{flt.hoursFlown}}</td>
    <td>{{flt.fuelHour}}</td>
    <td>{{flt.fuelIn}}</td>
    <td>{{flt.hoursLastOilChange}}</td>
    <td class="text-info">{{flt.oilChange}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The page's controller, with my method of getting the ID and passing it into the modal:

```
vm.popupReviewForm = function ($event) {
      var id = $event.currentTarget.attributes['id'].value;
      var modalInstance = $modal.open ({
        templateUrl : '/reviewModal/reviewModal.view.html',
        controller : 'reviewModalCtrl as vm',
        resolve : {
          data : function () {
            return {
              data : flightData.flight(id)
            };
          }
        }
      });
      modalInstance.result.then(function (data) {
        //
      });
    };
```

And my data service that makes an API call (I trust the API to function correctly):

```
var findOne = function (id) {
      return $http.get('/findone/' + id);
    };

    return {
      flightData : getData,
      flight : findOne
    };
```

Here is where I am stuck. The data produced in my resolve should be passed into the modal controller as flight.data, correct? Here is my modal controller:

```
angular
.module('loc8rApp')
.controller('reviewModalCtrl', reviewModalCtrl);



reviewModalCtrl.$inject = ['$modalInstance', 'loc8rData', 'flight'];
  function reviewModalCtrl ($modalInstance, loc8rData, flight) {
    var vm = this;
    vm.formError = "";
    vm.flight = flight.data;
    $log(vm.flight);
    vm.onSubmit = function () {

  if (!vm.data.fltDate || !vm.data.hobbsOut || !vm.data.fuelOut || !vm.data.oilDipstick) {
    vm.formError = "Hobbs Out, Fuel Out, Date, and Oil Dipstick are required!";
    console.log(vm.data);
    return false;
  } else {
    vm.formError = "";
    //
  }
};

vm.modal = {
  close : function (result) {
    $modalInstance.close(result);
  },
  cancel : function () {
    $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  }
};
}
```

This is some of the HTML markup for the form, with an example input field and my current attempt at binding the `vm.flight` object to my form:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="fltDate" class="col-xs-2 col-sm-2 control-label">Flight Date:</label>
    <div class="col-xs-10 col-sm-10">
      <input id="fltDate" name="fltDate" required="required" value="{{ vm.flight.flt_date }}" class="form-control"/> 
    </div>
  </div>
```

I know this is a lot of code but this issue is driving me nuts. Can't one just pass data into a controller through its argument like a normal function? All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest you **edit your post** instead of noting errors in comments.

Comment: Thanks, I'm a little new to stack overflow and couldn't find the button. For a minute I thought it was not editable, as I remember reading that some forms of editing come as a privilege.

Comment: i think the name used in the resolve object (i.e. `data`) is what should be injected into the controller instead of `flight`

Comment: Just tried that, no success. It seems with the flight : function(){ return data:  ... } syntax my data would be in flight.data, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's what jsonmurphy said above, but to expand a little, the resolves get passed into the controller as dependencies. So with how your controller is defined you could change the resolve to the following and it should work.

```
    resolve : {
      flight : function () {
        return {
          data : flightData.flight(id)
        };
      }
    }
```

Since flightData.flight(id) is returning a promise and you want the resolve to wait for it, try the following:

```
resolve: {
  flight: function(){ return flightData.flight(id); }
}
```

Comment: Thats what my resolve was originally. Hence why my HTML template says flight.data.property. I have tried this name, and flight.property and it still seems that the data is not available.

Comment: You don't have the implementation of flightData.flight in your question...can you add that or step through flightData.flight(id) and make sure it's returning the flight?

Comment: Sure, but it is just one API call, and I have both the ID and returned flight printing to the console in my API controller.

Comment: Well I can't edit the question at this point.. `var findOne = function (id) {
      if (id) { return $http.get('/findone/' + id); }
      else { return null; }
    };`

Comment: $http.get returns a promise for the response, not just the data. The resolve doesn't wait for the promise to resolve because you're wrapping it in another js object. Try directly returning flightData.flight(id) - I'll update the answer with that.

Comment: UglifyJS gives me parse errors if I try it that way. I didn't think you needed to wait for the resolve, because the whole two way data binding thing implies that when the data is available the view will be updated. This is how my list of things to be updated populates, which also includes and API call and works just fine.


I can pass hardcoded variables into the view, so maybe your suggestion is the root of the issue and perhaps I have to wait for the promise somewhere else. However, the code provided is not the correct answer.